# JavaScript: TypeError: element.include is not a function

Tags: javascript, include, arrow-functions

***CLOSED.*** forgot *s* in include**s** :(.

**H**ello, I'm new in JavaScript so I have got stuck with an arrow function and .isInclude Array method.
My array for experiments:

```
var yarr = [['age', [22, 23, 24, 26, 28]], 
            ['age', [11, 18, 24, 55, 88]],
            ['qwe', [11, 18, 24, 55, 88]]];
```

This code works good:

```
function  isIncludeValue(arrayOfArray, value){
    let accum = 0;
    for (let i = 0; i < arrayOfArray.length; i++) {
        accum =accum || (arrayOfArray[i].includes(value));
    }
    return accum;
}
 let e = isIncludeValue(yarr, 'qwe');
 console.log(e) //true
```

But this code give me TypeError:

```
function isIncludeTwo(arrayOfArray, value){
    let accum = 0;
    arrayOfArray.forEach(element =>  accum = accum || element.include(value))
    return accum;
}
let e = isIncludeTwo(yarr, 'qwe');
console.log(e)
//TypeError: element.include is not a function
//at arrayOfArray.forEach.element
```

And another thing in which I have doubt is storaging data in arrays, but the JS classes (sugared functions) seems to me too bulky for simple filtration task.

Comment: Replace  `element.include(value)` by `element.includes(value)`. Is a typo error!

Comment: Did you mean [`includes`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes)?

Comment: yeap, i have use in other code own include method and get mistake. thx, closed

Comment: When you get the error "x is not a function", you should always take the time to thoroughly reread your code and check for typos.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It should be `includes` not `include`